# how would i solve this vector equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The plane needs to go 505 mph and a bearing of 38 degrees to get to the destination on time. There is a southwestern wind going 50 mph. Determine what the pilot needs to set his speed at

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. This is not a "do it for me" site. If you [edit] the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck we may be able to help.

Comment: it took a while but im pretty sure I figured out how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not just a matter of speed. Velocity, both speed and direction, have to be set correctly.  We want a vector that, added to the wind vector, will give the desired velocity vector.

Start by drawing a picture.  You have one line with length 505 with angle 30 degrees from "up" and another, starting at the base of that first line, with length 50 and angle 180+ 45= 225 degrees.  The angle between those two lines is 360- 225+ 30= 135+ 30= 165 degrees.

Draw the third line connecting the ends of those two lines. You now have a triangle with two sides of lengths 50 and 505 with angle 165 degrees between them.  Use the cosine law and sine law to find the length and direction of the third side.

Comment: im just now seeing this. I figuered out how to do it after a while but thank you also for also helping me better understand it